# synchronizing animation with sound

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, animation

I created an array of images and animated them using:

```
imageview.animationImages = images;

imageview.animationDuration = 1;

imageview.animationRepeatCount = 1;

[imageview startAnimating];
```

Here `imageview` is a pointer to UIImageView object and `images` is the array. I am using a round rect button to fire the animation. When I run the animation for the first time after the simulator opens...the animation does not synchronize with the sound but after using it once when I press the button again it does. Any idea why? I am using system sound API to play short sound. I create an `id` for the sound and then play it using:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

My guess is that when I fire the animation for the first time, simulator takes some time to process the images I'm using and build the array. I am using 45 images in total. So as a consequence the sound stays ahead of the animated images. But when I try it again, the images are already processed so animation and sound, both are synchronized. But this is just a guess. I don't know what to do about this. If you wanna take a look at the whole code here it is:

```
-(IBAction)btnclicked:(id)sender { 
    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //all alloc does is allocate memory. The -init method is crucial to actually initialize the object into a working state.
    for (int imagenumber = 1; imagenumber <= 45; imagenumber++) {
        NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png", imagenumber];
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:myString]];
    }
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 460);
    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    imageview.animationImages = images;

    imageview.animationDuration = 3.2;

    imageview.animationRepeatCount = 1;

    [imageview startAnimating];

    [self.view addSubview:imageview];

    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"giggity stick around" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)url, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    [imageview release];

}
```

Just to avoid any confusion...my images are named 1.png, 2.png and so on thats why I used iteration when building an array.

Comment: https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIImageView/AVAudioPlayer synchronization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199015/uiimageview-avaudioplayer-synchronization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way is to create an function that play the sound something like this: -(void)playSound, then in your button action your should write a link to the playSound function: [self playSound].
here is a simple:

```
-(IBAction)XXX:(id)sender
{
    //your imagesArray
    [self playSound];
    imageview.animationDuration = 1;
    imageview.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [imageview startAnimating];
}

-(void)playSound
{
    //yourcode for playing the sound
}
```

hope its help.

edit:
try this:

```
-(IBAction)btnclicked:(id)sender { 
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //all alloc does is allocate memory. The -init method is crucial to actually initialize the object into a working state.
for (int imagenumber = 1; imagenumber <= 45; imagenumber++) {
    NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png", imagenumber];
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:myString]];
}
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 460);
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/giggity stick around.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
soundPlayer.volume = 1;
[soundPlayer play];    

imageview.animationImages = images;

imageview.animationDuration = 3.2;

imageview.animationRepeatCount = 1;

[imageview startAnimating];

[self.view addSubview:imageview];

}
```

i use the AVFoundation to play the audio, check this now.

Comment: it gives an error saying "Use of undeclared identifier 'soundplayer'" and it says the same thing for AVAudioPlayer. i think i need to add a framework for this like I used this for playing short system sound: `#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`

Comment: yes, you should include the AudioToolBox framework. also, you should declare the soundPlayer in the .h file(AVAudioPlayer *soundPlayer).

Comment: hey I read about using AVFoundation and did everything the way you said but still I am getting this very very strange error which says "  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:...." and "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" whats this?

Comment: but i did add `#include "AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h"` in the header file.

Comment: You still need to add the framework to the build settings. importing the headers as what you do after that.

Comment: thanks for helping. sound is working but its still not synced, I mean this only changed the sound to not work as a system sound but work as a long sound instead. And its not synced only for the first time?! strange...

Comment: Depending on your sound format, there could be a latency due to metadata loading/decompressing, that perhaps is cached the 2nd time. (I'm not an audio expert, but run in same kinds of problem) Maybe the problem was more to 'pre-load' sound, our choose quicker-loading format (ex: .wav)